# Laravel ORM - where, with and paginate

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

can someone help me with the following laravel ORM questions

I have 2 models ProductGroup and Product. ProductGroup hasMany Products and is linked via productGroup.product_id and product.id

I want to return a set of results with pagination. Quite simple wish, isn't it?

My current code is

```
$result = ProductGroup::where("name", "=", "laptop")
          ->with(array("product"=>function($q){
                        $q->select("id","name");
                    }))                 
          ->get(array("id","product_id","name","created_timestamp"));
```

It works but I cannot add ->paginate() otherwise it will throw the following error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()
```

What is the best way of doing the pagination? I can create the pagination manually (via `Paginator::make` )but I don't think it's good because it still returns the whole set of data (slowing down the traffic). I can use raw query to `limit` the result but it is also troublesome because I need to again manually calculate the total result

I am using Laravel 4.2 with MySQL

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which could help others

Wrong way

```
->get((array("id","product_id","name","created_timestamp"))
->paginate(3)
```

Correct way

```
->paginate(3, (array("id","product_id","name","created_timestamp"))
```

Feel free to downvote it if it is wrong